# expo document picker is not displaying to upload a file

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm new in react native. I'm learning it but I'm facing an issue working on `expo document picker`. I use the document picker, but it does not display anything showing or sometimes gives a promise rejection error.
I'm stuck at it for a long time today.

**upload.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import * as DocumentPicker from "expo";

const UploadFile = () => {
  pickDocument = async () => {
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
    console.log(result.uri);
    console.log(result);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
      <Text style={styles.file}>Upload CSV File</Text>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button
            title="upload your file"
            color="black"
            onPress={pickDocument}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor:
      "radial-gradient(ellipse at left bottom,    rgb(163, 237, 255) 0%,    rgba(57, 232, 255, 0.9) 59%,    rgba(48, 223, 214, 0.9) 100% )",
  },
  file: {
    color: "black",
    marginHorizontal: 145,
  },
  button: {
    marginHorizontal: 60,
  },
});

export default UploadFile;
```

I want to upload a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly install [expo-document-picker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/)

Secondly, Your Import Statement is wrong

On the third line you wrote
`import * as  DocumentPicker  from 'expo';` but you have to write `import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';`

I have corrected it. Check once.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import * as DocumentPicker from "expo-document-picker";

const UploadFile = () => {
  const pickDocument = async () => {
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
    console.log(result.uri);
    console.log(result);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
      <Text style={styles.file}>Upload CSV File</Text>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button
            title="upload your file"
            color="black"
            onPress={pickDocument}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor:
      "radial-gradient(ellipse at left bottom,    rgb(163, 237, 255) 0%,    rgba(57, 232, 255, 0.9) 59%,    rgba(48, 223, 214, 0.9) 100% )",
  },
  file: {
    color: "black",
    marginHorizontal: 145,
  },
  button: {
    marginHorizontal: 60,
  },
});

export default UploadFile;
```